# How to serve sites from http://ip/folder?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Please help.
I'm trying to setup 3 test sites, so each could be reached from my server's ip like:
my-server-ip/site1
my-server-ip/site2
my-server-ip/site3

When I use ServerName as ip it works fine:

```
 <VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080>
ServerName x.x.x.x
DocumentRoot "/home/myfolder/public_html"

<Directory "/home/myfolder/public_html">
        AllowOverride All
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

but using ServerName x.x.x.x/site1 is not working ofcourse.
I tryed to use Alias /site1 /path and it works for first virtual host but when i add 2 more virtual hosts to vhosts.conf only first works.

Another trick that i tryed is to add:

```
Alias /site1 /home/folder1/public_html
Alias /site2 /home/folder2/public_html
Alias /site3 /home/folder3/public_html
```

into /usr/local/apache/conf.d/domain-redirects.conf
and add  options into /usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf
And this does work but not correctly.

I know I could use some domain name and setup a buch of subdomains for other sites..but using ip is better.

Is there a way to set things up this way?

Answer (score 0):

You need to deposit your sites into the directory that the server accesses. The default that apache gives is /var/www. So if your file is at /var/www/test.html you can access it with 127.0.0.1:8080/test.html .

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! Your idea led to solution. Just in case someone needs the same setup, here is what i've done (running on Centos 6 + Apache+Varnish).

1. Create and upload folders/files just like you do for normal domains.

By default `http://ip` -> my apache looks into a folder:
/usr/local/apache/htdocs

I could create a folder here and upload a site here but rather I've created a symlink to my testsite:

```
ln -s /home/user/public_html/test_site_folder testsite1
```

now my testsite is available at `http://ip/testsite1`

almost...to make it work for user I added in httpd.conf this statement (AllowOverride) in order to be able to use mod_rewrite and others in .htaccess located in root folder of testsite1
*** added

```
<Directory "/usr/local/apache/htdocs">
    suPHP_UserGroup user user
    AllowOverride All  ***
    Order allow,deny   ***
    Allow from all     ***
```